# Process builder output and error redirection

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I am using `ProcessBuilder` to run an executable file from another directory. I'm also redirecting output and error to files in the local directory. But strangely my error file shows the output of the executable and the output file is blank. I am not sure what is going on, can someone please shed some light on my situation.

My code:

```
File outputFile = new File("outputLog.txt");
File errorFile = new File("ErrLog.txt");

List<String> command = Arrays.asList("c:\\dataloader\\TestDataLoader.exe", "-h");       
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

//redirect output
probuilder.redirectOutput(outputFile);
probuilder.redirectError(errorFile);

Process process = probuilder.start();
process.waitFor();

printFile(errorFile);    //writes to file
printFile(outputFile);   //writes to file

int exitValue = process.exitValue();
System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
```

Comment: Perhaps `TestDataLoader.exe` writes regular output to `STDERR` rather than `STDOUT`, this wouldn't be the first program to do that. Can you execute `TestDataLoader.exe` in a way which will cause an error and check your regular output file for the error? Also, did you create `TestDataLoader.exe`?

Comment: +1 to what Jonny said. Some commands, when invoked with `-h` to print help, do so on stderr not stdout (example on Linux: `bzip2 -h > /dev/null` still shows help text, because it is printed to stderr).