# Multiple unix globs in one unix command

Tags: unix, glob

So let's say I have 3 text files in a folder, `one.txt`, `two.txt`, and `three.txt`. I'd like to change all of them to markdown files. The dumb way is...

```
mv one.txt one.md
mv two.txt two.md
mv three.txt three.md
```

The way I'd like to do this is something like `mv *.txt *.md`, but that isn't working. Clearly the globs (`*`'s) aren't working how I think they're working. So I guess what I wanna do is something like...

`mv *.txt CAPTURED_GLOB_ITERANT.md`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. The shell expands your command to `mv one.txt three.txt two.txt *.md` (`*.md` remains unexpanded because no files match this pattern) before running `mv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell will not capture the patterns in a way that allows to do what you want, and `mv` itself does not do this either. So, with `mv` you would still need a loop anyway:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.md"; done
```

If you want to do that with one command, you'll need a specialized utility, such as `rename`:

```
rename 's/\.txt\z/.md/' *.txt
```

Comment: Common utilities include `rename` (the good one, written in Perl), `rename` (the crappy one from linux-util), and maybe `mmv`.

Comment: That should be `s/\.txt\z/.md/`. `.` is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped; `\z` matches at end-of-string (`$` matches at end of string but also at newline before end-of-string).

Comment: Ah yes, knew about dot, not about `\z`, thanks. Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852336/process-builder-output-and-error-redirection), so... that question might be closed anyway. And that answer also tells me I should have used `mv --`, to be safe with filenames that start with dashes...